# NestJs : How to implement node.js Post and Get logic in NestJs

Tags: nestjs

I'm trying to implement node.js Spotify Authorization flow in NestJs.

But HttpService Post and Get functions doesn't work as in node.js.

Node.js working example:

```
var request = require('request'); // "Request" library

app.get('/callback', function(req, res) {
    var authOptions = {
      url: 'https://some-url.com/api/token',
      form: {
        code: code,
        redirect_uri: redirect_uri,
        grant_type: 'authorization_code'
      },
      headers: {
        'Authorization': 'Basic ' + (Buffer.from(client_id + ':' + client_secret).toString('base64'))
      },
      json: true
    };

    // I'm trying to implement this post in NestJS
    request.post(authOptions, function(error, response, body) {
        var options = {
          url: 'https://api.spotify.com/v1/me',
          headers: { 'Authorization': 'Bearer ' + access_token },
          json: true
        };

        request.get(options, function(error, response, body) {
          console.log(body);
        });

}
```

I'm using HttpService Post method in NestJS 
and that doesn't work:

```
constructor(private httpService: HttpService) {}

@Get('callback')
callback(@Request() req, @Res() res): any {
  let code = req.query.code || null;
  const url = 'https://some-url.com/api/token';
  const form = {
    code: code,
    redirect_uri: this.redirect_uri,
    grant_type: 'authorization_code'
  }
  const headers = {
    'Authorization': 'Basic ' + (Buffer.from(this.client_id + ':' + this.client_secret))
  }

  // doesn't work
  this.httpService.post( url, form, { headers: headers }).pipe(
    map((response) => {
      console.log(response);
    }),
  );
}
```

Answer (score 2):

In NestJS, you do not need to send req, res object to your function parameter. Nest Js provide build-in decorator for `req.body`, `req.query` and `req.param` as `@Body`, `@Query`, and `@Param`. I write down to call post method and get method. You can also use put, patch, delete, and other methods. Please make a data transfer object file in your module.

for further reference, you can check this: https://docs.nestjs.com/controllers

```
export class yourController {
    constructor(private readonly httpService: HttpService) {}

    @Post('your-route-name')
    public postMethod(@Body() yourDTO: YourDTOClass): Promise<interface> {
        try {
            return this.httpService.method(yourDTO);
        } catch (err) {
            throw new HttpException(err, err.status || HttpStatus.BAD_REQUEST);
        }
    }

    @Get('your-route-name')
    find(@Query() query: QueryDTO): Promise<interface> {
        try {
            return this.httpService.methodName(query);
        } catch (err) {
            throw new HttpException(err, err.status || HttpStatus.BAD_REQUEST);
        }
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You should put `return` before `this.httpService.post(...)`. Normally you would have to subscribe to the Observable returned by the post method but NestJS handles this for you through the @Get() decorator.

Answer (score 0):

You should prefix your controller with "async" and use "await" followed by "toPromise()"...

```
constructor(private httpService: HttpService) {}

@Get('callback')
async callback(@Request() req, @Res() res): any {
  // ... remaining code here

  const response = 
    await this.httpService.post(url, form, { headers: headers }).toPromise();
  return response;
}
```

Comment: Were you able to solve this problem? If yes, upvote this or mark as solved, please.

Answer (score 0):

Add this imports to the controller:

```
import { Observable } from 'rxjs';
import { take, tap, map } from 'rxjs/operators';
```

Then try this:

```
constructor(private httpService: HttpService) {}

@Get('callback')
callback(@Request() req, @Res() res): Observable<any> {
  let code = req.query.code || null;
  const url = 'https://some-url.com/api/token';
  const form = {
    code: code,
    redirect_uri: this.redirect_uri,
    grant_type: 'authorization_code'
  }
  const headers = {
    'Authorization': 'Basic ' + (Buffer.from(this.client_id + ':' + 
    this.client_secret))
  }

  return this.httpService.post( url, form, { headers: headers }).pipe(
    // Take first result to complete the observable..
    take(1),
    
    // [OPTIONAL] Some debug log to see the response.
    tap((response: { data: any }) => {
       console.log(`Response: ${JSON.stringify(response.data)}`);
    })

    // Map the response object to just return its data. 
    map((response: { data: any }) => response.data),
  );
}
```